# Regex to match excessive whitespace in code

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace

I want to find and replace all whitespace that is shown below between `$`'s with just a single space.

**NOTE: I added the `$`'s manually to show you what I was looking to match. They are not actually present in the code - because if they were, it wouldn't compile!**

```
CClient::CClient$   $(Callback& callback):
    SecurityInfo$   $(NULL),
    ConnectInfo$    $(NULL),
    Session$    $(NULL),
    Id$         $(NULL),
    MyCallback$ $(callback),
    {
    unsigned long$           $something = 0;

    ConnectionId$            $= NumberOfClients++;

    SecurityInfo$            $= new SecurityInfoClass$  $();
    ConnectInfo$             $= new ConnectInfoClass$   $();
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
s/(?<!^)(?: ){2,}+|\t+(?=\S)/ /g
```

It works OK, but the check for the beginning-of-line doesn't work as I expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tabbing didn't translate well in my mock-up example, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Those $'s are just for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
s/(?<![ \t])(?!^)[ \t]{2,}(?![ \t])/ /mg;
```

Accepted this:

```
s/(?<![ \t])(?!^)[ \t]+(?![ \t])/ /mg;
```

Comment: Nearly, but it doesn't match single tabs in those cases, which I also need.

Comment: I guess it will just replace a single space with a single space. Yeah, that works as far as I know.